# How do I know the change in variables?

Tags: flutter, dart

Every time `onSelectedItemChanged` in period_list.dart works,
I want the variable `page` in plan_space.dart to be setState as it changes.
Should I make a stream?

period_list.dart

```
class PeriodList extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Container(
        child: ListWheelScrollView(
          itemExtent: size.height * 0.12,
          overAndUnderCenterOpacity: 0.5,
          onSelectedItemChanged: (value) {
            PlanSpace.page = value;
          },
.
.
.
```

plan_space.dart

```
class PlanSpace extends StatefulWidget {
  static int page;
  @override
  _PlanSpaceState createState() => _PlanSpaceState();
}

class _PlanSpaceState extends State<PlanSpace> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
    return Container(
      child: Center(
          child: Text(
        PlanSpace.page.toString(),
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 40.0),
      )),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the relationship between `PlanSpace` and `PeriodList`?

Comment: You can select a period from the `period_list` (Monthly, weekly, daily etc..)
The plan space then outputs a page for that period.

Comment: Asking about the relationship - I mean are they siblings (i.e. have the same parent)? I would recommend you to watch this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d_m5csmrf7I&feature=youtu.be to understand State Management in Flutter.

Comment: in onSelectedItemChanged, call a method in PlanSpaceState that calls setState